# Glassfish Logs Date and DST?

Tags: java, logging, glassfish, dst

So, the system time on my Ubuntu server updated appropriately with DST on Sunday.

However, the timestamp on my glassfish logs are still an hour off. I've restarted the application server, but this doesn't seem to have changed anything.

A quick hello-world indicates that the JVM grabs the (correct) system time. Any ideas on why 
the time in the glassfish logs do not match the system or JVM date and time?

As suggested, I've also run the `tzupdate` tool. This does not seem to have done much.

Any ideas what's going on? How can I repair this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to update the JVM to get the latest time zone information. Or use the [Timezone Updater Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html).

Comment: +1, though `tzupdate` didn't seem to do the trick... thanks anyway!